# How to produce a single line output of a record with jq

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON

```
{
   "guid": "dce38b4b-9989-42d2-b6bd-702645e344cf",
   "name": "dev",
   "apps": [
      {
         "guid": "5d5498cb-a885-4242-a55a-d7d286a1cf48",
         "urls": [
            "nodered.cloudfoundry.org"
         ],
         "routes": [
            {
               "guid": "aca4d04b-f99d-4b43-afaa-82ab41afa07c",
               "host": "nodered-test",
               "port": null,
               "path": "",
               "domain": {
                  "guid": "f4b90d7e-2cd3-4d30-b200-f28bbaf6be20",
                  "name": "cloudfoundry.org"
               }
            }
         ],
         "service_count": 1,
         "service_names": [
            "nodered-test-cloudantNoSQLDB"
         ],
         "running_instances": 1,
         "name": "perik-nodered-test",
         "production": false,
         "space_guid": "dce38b4b-9989-42d2-b6bd-702645e344cf",
         "stack_guid": "ac91d31a-86a3-453b-babf-8d49c9d763fc",
         "buildpack": null,
         "detected_buildpack": "SDK for Node.js(TM) (ibm-node.js-6.13.0, buildpack-v3.20-20180403-1426)",
         "detected_buildpack_guid": "33e9e82f-8846-4362-a60a-92964285a31e",
         "environment_json": {},
         "memory": 256,
         "instances": 1,
         "disk_quota": 1024,
         "state": "STARTED",
         "version": "8c8c97a0-bc2e-424c-a0a3-d64704feb634",
         "command": null,
         "console": false,
         "debug": null,
         "staging_task_id": "539f460c-e4d2-49f9-b5e5-9f4fd31a8370",
         "package_state": "STAGED",
         "health_check_type": "port",
         "health_check_timeout": null,
         "health_check_http_endpoint": null,
         "staging_failed_reason": null,
         "staging_failed_description": null,
         "diego": true,
         "docker_image": null,
         "package_updated_at": "2018-04-10T17:32:06Z",
         "detected_start_command": "./vendor/initial_startup.rb",
         "enable_ssh": true,
         "ports": null
      },
      {
         "guid": "4089ce19-19fb-467b-8876-3635819d5d91",
         "urls": [
            "nodered.cloudfoundry.org"
         ],
         "routes": [
            {
               "guid": "b79988d8-5ac5-455d-8fdd-00bc208dd2bc",
               "host": "NodeRedTestApp",
               "port": null,
               "path": "",
               "domain": {
                  "guid": "f4b90d7e-2cd3-4d30-b200-f28bbaf6be20",
                  "name": "cloudfoundry.org"
               }
            }
         ],
         "service_count": 1,
         "service_names": [
            "NodeRedTestApp-cloudantNoSQLDB"
         ],
         "running_instances": 1,
         "name": "perik-NodeRedTestApp",
         "production": false,
         "space_guid": "dce38b4b-9989-42d2-b6bd-702645e344cf",
         "stack_guid": "ac91d31a-86a3-453b-babf-8d49c9d763fc",
         "buildpack": null,
         "detected_buildpack": "SDK for Node.js(TM) (ibm-node.js-6.13.0, buildpack-v3.20-20180403-1426)",
         "detected_buildpack_guid": "33e9e82f-8846-4362-a60a-92964285a31e",
         "environment_json": {},
         "memory": 256,
         "instances": 1,
         "disk_quota": 1024,
         "state": "STARTED",
         "version": "17175bdb-df93-4745-9a17-cf214fe05976",
         "command": null,
         "console": false,
         "debug": null,
         "staging_task_id": "5c74633a-25db-4adf-9eb8-09454a70be52",
         "package_state": "STAGED",
         "health_check_type": "port",
         "health_check_timeout": null,
         "health_check_http_endpoint": null,
         "staging_failed_reason": null,
         "staging_failed_description": null,
         "diego": true,
         "docker_image": null,
         "package_updated_at": "2018-04-09T21:23:27Z",
         "detected_start_command": "./vendor/initial_startup.rb",
         "enable_ssh": true,
         "ports": null
      }
   ]

}
```

and getting the following values using

cat test.json | jq -r '.apps[].routes[].host, .apps[].state, .apps[].package_updated_at' which produces the following output

nodered-test
NodeRedTestApp
STARTED
STARTED
2018-04-10T17:32:06Z
2018-04-09T21:23:27Z

How can I get the output as

nodered-test STARTED 2018-04-10T17:32:06Z
NodeRedTestApp STARTED 2018-04-09T21:23:27Z

So that I can assign it to a bash script array.

Comment: The name `routes` is plural, and the value of .routes is an array, so it would seem possible that there is more than one element in the array. 
 What should be done if that were the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.apps[] | [.routes[].host, .state, .package_updated_at] | join(" ")' test.json
```

The output:

```
nodered-test STARTED 2018-04-10T17:32:06Z
NodeRedTestApp STARTED 2018-04-09T21:23:27Z
```